# Is it possible to only update array state of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I was wondering if there is any documentation or reference that could help me to to understand how to update a state of objects array (Without duplicates).

My state looks like this:

```
accounts: [
    { name: ‘mike’ },
    { name: ‘tee’ },
    { name: ‘ralf’ },
    { name: ‘candy’ },
    { name: ‘bon’ },
    { name: ‘salm’ },
    { name: ‘shark’ },
    { name: ‘tof’ },
    { name: ‘hulk’ },
    { name: ‘zar’ },
    { name: ‘blake’ },
  ],
```

the upcoming array is like this:

```
accounts: [
    { name: 'mike’, balance: ’1000’},
    { name: 'tee’, balance: ’235345’},
    { name: 'zar’, balance: ’3455’},
    { name: 'candy’, balance: ’567567’},
    { name: 'tee’, balance: ’8767’},
    { name: 'salm', balance: ’234’},
    { name: 'blake', balance: ’134’},
  ],
```

So the updated state on setState will look like this:

```
accounts: [
    { name: 'mike’, balance: ’1000’},
    { name: 'tee’, balance: ’235345’},
    { name: ‘ralf’ },
    { name: 'candy’, balance: ’567567’},
    { name: ‘bon’ },
    { name: 'salm', balance: ’234’},
    { name: ‘shark’ },
    { name: ‘tof’ },
    { name: ‘hulk’ },
    { name: 'zar’, balance: ’3455’},
    { name: 'blake', balance: ’134’},
  ],
```

I have tried with `prevState.accounts.concat(accounts)` but it only adds duplicates.

Comment: If your `accounts` don't have duplicate names, wouldn't it make more sense for this to be an object? Then this would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find object based on condition and then update values where use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to find the element and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method to copy values to an existing object.

```
accounts.forEach( o => {
   let oldObj = prevState.accounts.find(o1 => o1.name === o.name);
   Object.assign(oldObj, o)
})
```

---

Final code would be like :

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  newAccounts.forEach(o => {
    let oldObj = prevState.accounts.find(o1 => o1.name === o.name);
    Object.assign(oldObj, o)
  })
  return prevState.accounts
});
```

Oneliner solution by creating a new array.

```js
this.setState(prevState => newAccounts.map(o => Object.assign(prevState.accounts.find(o1 => o1.name === o.name), o)));

// if you don't want to mutate original object in previous state then

this.setState(prevState => newAccounts.map(o => Object.assign({}, prevState.accounts.find(o1 => o1.name === o.name), o)));

// or with ES6 spread syntax
this.setState(prevState => newAccounts.map(o => ({ ...prevState.accounts.find(o1 => o1.name === o.name), ...o }))));
```

Comment: Id use `{}` as the first argument to make it pure.

Comment: @JonasWilms : depends on his need ... `{...oldObj, ...o}` or `Object.assign({}, oldObj, o)`

Comment: Many thanks. This seems to be helpful but how do I use this method to setState?

Comment: @mediaroot `this.setState(prevState => {
  newAccounts.forEach(o => {
    let oldObj = prevState.accounts.find(o1 => o1.name === o.name);
    Object.assign(oldObj, o)
    return prevState.accounts
  })
});`

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If your new state accounts is always going to be subset of the previous state accounts value. You can use something like this

```
this.state = {
    accounts : [
        { name: 'mike' },
        { name: 'tee' },
        { name: 'ralf' },
        { name: 'candy' },
        { name: 'bon' },
        { name: 'salm' },
        { name: 'shark' },
        { name: 'tof' },
        { name: 'hulk' },
        { name: 'zar' },
        { name: 'blake' },
    ]
}
const newAccounts = [
    { name: 'mike', balance: 1000},
    { name: 'tee', balance: 235345},
    { name: 'zar', balance: 3455},
    { name: 'candy', balance: 567567},
    { name: 'tee', balance: 8767},
    { name: 'salm', balance: 234},
    { name: 'blake', balance: 134},
]
this.setState({accounts: this.state.accounts.map (x => ({...x, ...newAccounts.find(y => y.name === x.name)}))});
```

You can use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the values of old state accounts in new accounts and then use [...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) or [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge properties.

Comment: Wouldn't this mutate the prevState's objects?

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, this will always going to be subset

Comment: no, this will not mutate because .map will return a new array and I am using ... to destructure and return new objects for this array